# Unix : How to modify and redirect stdout of all running processes

Tags: linux, unix, redirect, awk

I want to modify and redirect the output of all running process. I know that if i know the name of the process i can do something like this

```
process 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

which will redirect stderr and stdout to dev/null. First, how would i modify the stdout before sending it to dev/null or anywhere else? One possible solution is

```
process 2>&1 | awk '{print "$SOME_ENV_VAR|" $0;}' > dev/null
```

is this the correct way? Does it endure that both stdout and stderr are redirected?

1. What if instead of redirecting to dev/null, i want to print to console?
2. The bigger problem is, how to do this for each running process? I need to do this in a linux box where i dont know the names of  the processes running. Is that feasible?

I am fairly new to shell scripting so please forgive me is these questions are trivial.

Comment: First, you should state which kind of shell you are using. With linux, mostlikely you are using bash. Then, _running processes_ suggests you are trying to modify I/O assignments _after_ having started a process - this is not possible (at least without special kernel support). Your examples, however, suggest you head for spefying I/O at process start. Last, you should give more dertails on what you want to achieve. sh (and thus also bash) is quite powerful in how stin/stdout/stderr of processes can be connected to each other.

Comment: thanks, i just noticed that `awk '{print "$SOME_ENV_VAR|" $0;}'` does not cathc the env variable. how can i use the environment var in awk?

Comment: This is not a property of `awk` but a consequence of you using single quotes (`'`) with the `awk` script parameter. It would interpolate if e.g. you did use: `awk '{print '"$SOME_ENV_VAR|"' $0;}'`. However, this would just prepend the value from `$SOME_ENV_VAR` to each line from `process` before sending it doe `/dev/null`.

Comment: Alternatively, you coud use the `-v` switch to `awk` to assign a variable. In your case e.g.: `awk -v var="$SOME_ENV_VAR" '{ print var "|" $0;}'`

Comment: great! thanks that works

Comment: ok, you were right. turns out i dont need to look for all running process. i would have the list of processes and then i just apply the awk as you suggested. If you put your comments as an answer, i will gladly accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the discussion it turned out that you not really intended 
to redirect the output of already running processes to somewhere else. But you seem to be trying to modify the output of a process you are starting .

With bash (seems to be what you are using) you may use `[FD]>TARGET` resp. `[FD]<SOURCE` for specifying the I/O channels of a process. `FD` is optional and a file descriptor number. Leaving it out implies `0` (=stdin) on `<` and `1` (=stdout) on `>`. (`2` is the well-known file descriptor for stderr). `TARGET` or `SOURCE` my be file system objects (e.g. files, devices, named pipes, unix domain sockets) or `&FD` where `FD` again is a file descriptor number and indicates the (open) filedescriptor to use.

You will use it e.g to cause the error output to be sent to where stdout is going to by writing to: `2>&1`.

If you now want to postprocess the output from a process (actually this is a pipeline in shell terminology as it could be any complex (shell) statement consisting itself of several commands and I/O redirections.)
 you will use a pipe: (`A | B`).
This basically connects stdout of process A with stdin of process B.

For manipulating output you may use any other unix command or program. Most common are `sed` (for applying regular expression based replacements) or `awk`. Others might also recommend `perl` or `python`.

In your case you intend to prepend each line by a prefix given by some environment variable.

Using `awk` you could write it as follows:

```
awk '{ print "'"$SOME_ENV_VAR"'|" $0;}'
```

or passing in the external value as an awk variable:

```
awk -v var="$SOME_ENV_VAR" '{ print var "|" $0;}'
```

To take this a little bit further:

Output redirection with bash is quite powerful. E.g you could pass stdout to one pipe and sterr to another. For example :

```
(((echo hallo; echo ERROR >&2) | awk '{ print "stdout|" $0; }' >&4) 2>&1|  awk '{ print "stderr: " $0;}' ) 4>&1
```

This will process stdout and sterr by separate awk instances and send the (combined) output to the normal stdout of the shell.

Comment: great! thanks. what does 4 mean here? 1 is stdout, 2 is stderr and i think 3 is debug. is that right?

Comment: A filedescriptor is an integer (>=0). Actually this is an index into the process specific open file table. The maximum is system dependend. Use ulimit -n to get the current maximum fpor your system. I just deliberatly have choosen "4" here . The only requirement was: different from the already open standard descriptor values (0,1,2). The `4>&1` is opening this descriptor. The `>&4` is using it. (The schell is issuing a `dup` system calls for these.)  0,1,2 are managed by the shell and as such "well-known" anything else is up to programs and users.